# Why a message loses its content when it is passed to another thread?

Tags: java, android

during the development of an Android application, I found a (In my opinion) very strange behavior.
By passing a message object (android.os.Message) into another thread it loses all its content. Could someone perhaps explain to me why this is happening? I wrote an example application to illustrate the problem:

MainActivity:

```
package com.test.bundletest;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Messenger mOutMsger;

    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mOutMsger = new Messenger(service);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            sendMultipleMessages(10);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void sendMultipleMessages(int messageCount){
        if (mOutMsger!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i<messageCount; i++){
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("test", "Just a test");
                msg.setData(b);
                msg.what = i;
                try {
                    mOutMsger.send(msg);
                    System.out.println("Message sent");
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Messenger was null");
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
package com.test.bundletest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private ExecutorService mExe = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler mInHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            System.out.println(
                    new StringBuilder(" UI Thread - What? - ")
                            .append(msg.what)
                            .append("Data? - ")
                            .append(msg.peekData() == null)
                            .append(" KeySet size? - ")
                            .append(msg.getData().keySet().size()));
            mExe.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(
                            new StringBuilder(" NonUI Thread - What? - ")
                                    .append(msg.what)
                                    .append("Data? - ")
                                    .append(msg.peekData() == null)
                                    .append(" KeySet size? - ")
                                    .append(msg.getData().keySet().size()));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private final Messenger mInMessenger = new Messenger(mInHandler);

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mInMessenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Connected
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out: Message sent
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 0Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 1Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 2Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 3Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 4Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 5Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 6Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 7Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 8Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8751/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  UI Thread - What? - 9Data? - false KeySet size? - 1
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
8751-8809/com.test.bundletest I/System.out:  NonUI Thread - What? - 0Data? - true KeySet size? - 0
```

It's even stranger that if I copy the message just before handling it over, this doesn't happen:

```
package com.test.bundletest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private ExecutorService mExe = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler mInHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            System.out.println(
                    new StringBuilder(" UI Thread - What? - ")
                            .append(msg.what)
                            .append("Data? - ")
                            .append(msg.peekData() == null)
                            .append(" KeySet size? - ")
                            .append(msg.getData().keySet().size()));
            final Message msg2 = Message.obtain(msg);
            mExe.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(
                            new StringBuilder(" NonUI Thread - What? - ")
                                    .append(msg2.what)
                                    .append("Data? - ")
                                    .append(msg2.peekData() == null)
                                    .append(" KeySet size? - ")
                                    .append(msg2.getData().keySet().size()));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private final Messenger mInMessenger = new Messenger(mInHandler);

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mInMessenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

Running it this way, the output ist identical for UI and NON UI Thread.

I am at the end of my Java knowledge and hope that someone can explain this to me understandably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `Message.obtain();` that returns a new Message instance from the global pool.

When you create a new thread the method `handleMessage(Message msg)` finishes execution and the object Message that still belongs to the global pool is recycling. So in the new thread this object is already empty

In your service you can do this:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    final Message message = new Message();
    message.copyFrom(msg);
    //your code
}
```

Or you can map `Message` object into your own custom object. It is better to use the `Message` object only for data transfer through the `Handler`

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be exactly the descripted way. The message object is recycled after handleMessage(Message msg) finished. If I delay the end of the method, the data will be preserved. It's a pity that this procedure is apparently not described in the documentation.